# How to create a fog effect in XNA with PixelShaderFunction?

Tags: xna, game-design, graphic-effects, fragment-shader, effects

I developped a small XNA games in 3D.
I would like to add a "**fog of war**" on my models instantiated **with an effect** in my **(.fx)** file.
The problem is, I do not know how to change the function
"PixelShaderFunction".

File [.fx]

Here is the **declaration of my variables** in my effect file (.fx):

```
// InstancedModel.fx
//
// Microsoft XNA Community Game Platform
// Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Camera settings.
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

//Fog settings
float FogNear;
float FogFar;
float4 FogColor;
```

And my **function "PixelShaderFunction"** in my effect file (.fx):

```
// Both techniques share this same pixel shader.
float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    return tex2D(Sampler, input.TextureCoordinate) * input.Color;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "fog of war"? Is it about putting fog where there are no units in a strategy game? or about 3D fog where things get fainter as they get farther from the point of view?

Comment: i think about the 3D fog where things get fainter as they get farther from the point of view

Comment: You made the exact same question, and you even accepted it. If you got your question solved, why did you make a new one? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50905

Comment: Because the old answer was correct! I asked how to apply a fog of war! Now I wonder how to create a function in my file PixelToShader. fx

Comment: And anyway I can not delete because someone called attention to a moderator ...super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look in XNA's BasicEffect shader source and see how they have implemented Fog support there.

The source code is available [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/downloads/?id=484&filename=StockEffectsSample_4_0.zip).

Comment: Yes I know it is much easier to integrate a fog with class "BasicEffect". However, for other special reasons, I have to use the class "Effect" with a file. "Fx". Because I use an importer of special model for the technique "Model Instancing".And your link does not work for info ... ^ ^

Comment: I understand that there might be numerous reasons to use your own custom shader instead of BasicEffect. The link I provided contains a downloadable zip which contains all XNA stock effect files in their raw HLSL format. I suggested that it might be a good starting point to look how they have implemented Fog effect. I cannot help other than that as I am not that familiar with Fog effect principles myself.

Comment: Ok thank you. It's already help me a lot. However I do not see where is your link .. The link mentioned above does not work. (dead link?)

Comment: I wonder why the link didn't work ... anyway, I have changed it so it points to direct download link of the sample (hope it isn't against the rules). Let me know if there are still problems.

Comment: Super. Thank you very much! Everything works perfectly now. Vai I take a look at these data. And I come back to keep you informed ;-).

Comment: Thank you very much i found everything I wanted in your link! It ay of example file (. Fx) with a variable declaration 'fog' function and necessary. I mark as solved